# Redirecionar site para outro servidor via DNS

Tags: dns

tudo bem?

Estou com uma dúvida. Tenho dois servidores: Locaweb (Plano Windows) e Hostgator (Plano Linux).

No plano da Locaweb estão os e-mails e arquivos de um sistema interno da empresa feito em ASP. No plano Hostgator está o site da empresa e gerenciador do mesmo.

Como eu faço uma entrada de DNS do tipo CNAME na Locaweb para redirecionar apenas o site para o servidor da Hostgator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pergunta é antiga mas acredito que vale a pena responder

Você deve apontar o A record para o `IP` do site no `hostgator`, faça:

```
website.com -> IP
www.website.com ->IP
```

Para o email do Locaweb continuar funcionando você deve levar os `CNAME` para o hostgator, consulte-os e veja quais são necessárias, mas é bem provável que você tenha que fazer:

`Mx` do `locaweb` colocar passar para o `mx` no `hostgator`, `smtp` e `pop` do `locaweb` passar para o `hostgador`.

```
Mx
website.com -> algumserver.com

CNAME
smtp.website.com -> smtp.algumserver.com
```

E ai podemos ter pop, mail, pop3 ou até correio

```
pop.website.com -> pop.algumserver.com
```

É justamente este **algumserver** que devemos consultar os manuais ou entrar em contato com o suporte para ter acesso. Caso você tenha acesso a estes dados pelo painel, basta coloca-los no `hostgator`.